# SQL query to have separate column with two joins relation

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, duplicates

I would like to join the table `core_loan` with two other tables `core_loan_specific_materials` and `core_loangenericitem`.
`Core_loan` has one reference column for each table:

```
 Loan_table
 id | specificmaterialinstance_id | material_id
```

The resultset always returns both specific values and generic_object in a same row

Ex: ***Loan with two materials and one specific_object***

```
| id  | specificmaterialinstance_id | material_id
| 211 | 3                           | 4
| 211 | 3                           | 20
```

How to have separate objects in result and by pass the different number of columns (2 for materials and one for specificinstance) :

```
| id  | specificmaterialinstance_id | material_id
| 211 | 3                           | NULL
| 211 | NULL                        | 4
| 211 | NULL                        | 20
```

This is the query :

```
SELECT loan.id,
       loan.status, loan.specificmaterialinstance_id, loan.material_id   
FROM(
     SELECT * FROM "main"."core_loan" as l 
     LEFT JOIN "main"."core_loan_specific_materials" as ls ON ls.loan_id = l.id       
     LEFT JOIN "main"."core_loangenericitem" as lg ON lg.loan_id = l.id        
     WHERE ("due_date" < date("now",'-1 day')) 
) AS loan
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your question references one table, but your query references three, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join separately `"main"."core_loan"` to each of the tables and then use `UNION ALL` to combine the results:

```
SELECT l.id, ls.specificmaterialinstance_id, null material_id     
FROM "main"."core_loan" as l
LEFT JOIN "main"."core_loan_specific_materials" as ls ON ls.loan_id = l.id
WHERE (l."due_date" < date("now",'-1 day'))
UNION ALL
SELECT l.id, null, lg.material_id    
FROM "main"."core_loan" as l
LEFT JOIN "main"."core_loangenericitem" as lg ON lg.loan_id = l.id
WHERE (l."due_date" < date("now",'-1 day'))
```

I assume `"due_date"` is a column in the table `"main"."core_loan"`.

Comment: yes due_date is a column of loan table. I've tried your solution, but the number of colums in result is different (2 for materials and one for specific)

Comment: @user5329403 Both unioned queries return 3 columns. I missed an alias in the 1st query which I edited now.

Comment: Ok, it's what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select id, specificmaterialinstance_id, NULL material_id
from loan
union all
select id, NULL, material_id 
from loan;
```

Comment: Here the Join is missing.